# Pandas yahoo finance DataReader

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the Adj Close prices from Yahoo Finance into a DataFrame. I have all the stocks I want but I am not able to sort on date.

```
stocks = ['ORCL', 'TSLA', 'IBM','YELP', 'MSFT']
ls_key = 'Adj Close'
start = datetime(2014,1,1)
end = datetime(2014,3,28)    
f = web.DataReader(stocks, 'yahoo',start,end)


cleanData = f.ix[ls_key]
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(cleanData)

print dataFrame[:5]
```

I get the following result, which is almost perfect.

```
              IBM   MSFT   ORCL    TSLA   YELP
Date                                           
2014-01-02  184.52  36.88  37.61  150.10  67.92
2014-01-03  185.62  36.64  37.51  149.56  67.66
2014-01-06  184.99  35.86  37.36  147.00  71.72
2014-01-07  188.68  36.14  37.74  149.36  72.66
2014-01-08  186.95  35.49  37.61  151.28  78.42
```

However, the Date is not an Item. so when I run:

```
print dataFrame['Date']
```

I get the error:

```
KeyError: u'no item named Date'
```

Hope anyone can help me adding the Date.

Comment: Date is your index, so dataFrame.index, this will get you the date column

Comment: you can do `dataFrame["Date"] = dataframe.index` if you want to add a column called 'Date' with the index values in it

Answer (score 11):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime    

start = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 27)
df = web.DataReader("GOOGL", 'yahoo', start, end)

dates =[]
for x in range(len(df)):
    newdate = str(df.index[x])
    newdate = newdate[0:10]
    dates.append(newdate)

df['dates'] = dates

print df.head()
print df.tail()
```

Comment: First, get data into pandas 'dataframe' with pandas 'datareader ', second, slice 'dataframe' index (which has date info) to get just date, third, add 'date' dates to 'dataframe'...

Answer (score 7):

Date is in the index values.

To get it into a column value, you should just use:

```
dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=False)
```

Then you can use

```
dataframe['Date']
```

because "Date" will now be one of the keys in your columns of the dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Use `dataFrame.index` to directly access date or to add an explicit column, use `dataFrame["Date"] = dataframe.index`

```
stocks = ['ORCL', 'TSLA', 'IBM','YELP', 'MSFT']
ls_key = 'Adj Close'
start = datetime(2014,1,1)
end = datetime(2014,3,28)    
f = web.DataReader(stocks, 'yahoo',start,end)


cleanData = f.ix[ls_key]
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(cleanData)
dataFrame["Date"] = dataframe.index
print dataFrame["Date"] ## or print dataFrame.index
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

symbols_list = ['ORCL', 'TSLA', 'IBM','YELP', 'MSFT']
d = {}
for ticker in symbols_list:
    d[ticker] = DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", '2014-12-01')
pan = pd.Panel(d)
df1 = pan.minor_xs('Adj Close')
print(df1)

#df_percent_chg = df1.pct_change()
```

Comment: could you please a take a look this question? i also use a list as pandas datareader input, but some tickers fail to be read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63952241/pandas-datareader-fail-to-read-symbol-from-yahoo

Answer (score 1):

The sub-package pandas.io.data is removed from the latest pandas package and it is available to install separately as [pandas-datareader](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader)

use git to install the package.
in the linux terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader.git
cd pandas-datareader
python setup.py install
```

now you can use `import pandas_datareader` to your python script for Remote data Access.

For more information [Use this link to visit the latest documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html)

Answer (score 0):

`f` is a `Panel`
You can get a `DataFrame` and reset index (Date) using:

```
f.loc['Adj Close',:,:].reset_index()
```

but I'm not sure `reset_index()` is very useful as you can get Date using

```
f.loc['Adj Close',:,:].index
```

You might have a look at
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing
about indexing

Answer (score 0):

print(dataFrame.index[0])

2014-01-02 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
web.DataReader('GOOGL', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Comment: `df = web.DataReader('GOOGL', 'yahoo', start, end)` then `print(df)`