# Filter on the closest available date to month-end in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

Using python and pandas I am trying to download security price data from Yahoo Finance with the aim of ending up with the month-end adjusted price in a time series.

My code is shown below. I have used ix to filter the dataframe to produce a list of business month-end dates. This works for all but 2 dates in the time series, where 31 May 2010 and 29 March 2013 both appear as blanks, and I think is because these are federal holidays in the US.

Rather than going down the route of trying to create a calendar for trading days, is it possible to create a custom frequency or calendar that simply looks for the month-end date, and if it is not available, checks the previous dates until it finds a value? For example, 31 March 2013 has no data, so check for 30 March (no data), 29 March (no data), 28 March (data) -> display 28 March in series.

```
import io
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import pandas

ticker = 'SPY'
start_date = '2009-12-31'
end_date = '2016-12-08'
s_dt = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
e_dt = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

url = 'http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s={0}&a={1}&b={2}&c={3}&d={4}&e={5}&f={6}&g=d&ignore=.csv'
url = url.format(ticker, s_dt.month-1, s_dt.day, s_dt.year, e_dt.month-1, e_dt.day, e_dt.year)
data = requests.get(url).content

df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(data.decode('utf-8')))
df.drop('Open', 1, inplace=True)
df.drop('High', 1, inplace=True)
df.drop('Low', 1, inplace=True)
df.drop('Volume', 1, inplace=True)
df.drop('Close', 1, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['date', ticker]

df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')    
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.ix[pandas.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='BM')]
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `pandas_datareader`? see for ex. this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991567/pandas-yahoo-finance-datareader

Comment: Thanks - I had never heard of pandas_datareader before. Will look into it.

Comment: You need to `pip install` it if you do not have it already. Then you would just do `from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader ` and your full frame of data would be `df = DataReader('SPY', 'yahoo', '2009-12-31', '2016-12-08')`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out a way of achieving what I wanted by using the fillna method.

The last line of the my original code should be replaced with:

```
# expand series to add all dates in date range
df = df.ix[pandas.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='d')]
# fill in the NaN values with the last available value
df = df.fillna(method='pad')
# reduce series to just business month-end dates
df = df.ix[pandas.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='BM')]
```

Comment: Don't use `.ix` unless you really have to. Use `.loc` and `.loc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the raw daily data with `pandas_datareader` (`pip install` it if you do not have it already)

Then you would just do

```
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
df = DataReader('SPY', 'yahoo', '2009-12-31', '2016-12-08')
```

You could skip the post processing step and get the monthly data directly, but the interface for this was a bit more finicky, you would do:

```
from pandas_datareader.yahoo.daily import YahooDailyReader 
df_monthly = YahooDailyReader('SPY', '2009-12-31', '2016-12-08', interval='m').read()
```