# pandas merge two dataframe to form a multiindex

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

I'm playing around with Pandas to see if I can do some stock calculation better/faster than with other tools. If I have a single stock it's easy to create daily calculation L

```
df['mystuff'] = df['Close']+1
```

If I download more than a ticker it gets complicated:

```
df = df.stack() 
df['mystuff'] = df['Close']+1
df = df.unstack()
```

If I want to use prevous' day "Close" it gets too complex for me. I thought I might go back to fetch a single ticker, do any operation with iloc[i-1] or something similar (I haven't figured it yet) and then merge the dataframes.

How do I merget two dataframes of single tickers to have a multiindex?
So that:

```
f1 = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)
f2 = web.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

is like

```
f = web.DataReader(['AAPL','GOOG'], 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Edit:
This is the nearest thing to f I can create. It's not exactly the same so I'm not sure I can use it instead of f.

```
f_f = pd.concat(['AAPL':f1,'GOOG':f2},axis=1)
```

Maybe I should experiment with operations working on a multiindex instead of splitting work on simpler dataframes.

Full Code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2001, 9, 1)
end = datetime(2019, 8, 31)
a = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)
g = web.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', start, end)
# here are shift/diff calculations that I don't knokw how to do with a multiindex
a_g = web.DataReader(['AAPL','GOOG'], 'yahoo', start, end)
merged = pd.concat({'AAPL':a,'GOOG':g},axis=1)

a_g.to_csv('ag.csv')
merged.to_csv('merged.csv')
import code; code.interact(local=locals())
```

side note: I don't know how to compare the two csv

Comment: what about concat and then do a group by on ('yahoo',start,end) ?

Comment: well, you won't get the same result. I can use concat({'AAPL':f...) but it's not like a multiindex

Comment: pd.concat(['AAPL':f1,'GOOG':f2},axis=1) is the nearest thing I was able to accomplish

Comment: the idea is that you don't care about the multi index in the concat, if you have the same columns in both of the dataframe. The multi index is handled by the group by

Comment: @Mayeulsgc I'm a bit lost. I suppose you made a mistake on your previous answer, since "yahoo",start,end are parameter for the data provider.

Comment: ah ! Alright can you give a sample of the datframes you want to perform the concat/merger on ?

Comment: @Mayeulsgc full code added. store a, g, a_g immediately on a pickle/csv if you don't want to fetch data from yahoo every time you test it.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991567/pandas-yahoo-finance-datareader) post looks like your line `f = web.DataReader(['AAPL','GOOG'], 'yahoo', start, end)` should work, what do you get?

Comment: I am trying to add values to both AAPL and GOOG. if I use the single df it's easy: a['NEW'] = a['Close'].shift() ...and so on.(reindex and all works..) If I try the multiindex, I can't add a "NEW" for "AAPL" and for "GOOG" . especially if I want to use it's data to fill (like "take Close and multipily with the previous close for each one of the stocks)

Comment: @maugch could you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly the same but it returns Multiindex you can use as in the `a_g` case

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2019, 7, 1)
end = datetime(2019, 8, 31)
out = []
for tick in ["AAPL", "GOOG"]:
    d = web.DataReader(tick, 'yahoo', start, end)
    cols = [(col, tick) for col in d.columns]
    d.columns = pd.MultiIndex\
                  .from_tuples(cols,
                               names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'] )
    out.append(d)

df = pd.concat(out, axis=1)
```

**Update**

In case you want to calculate and add a new column in case you have multiindex columns you can follow this

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2019, 7, 1)
end = datetime(2019, 8, 31)

ticks = ['AAPL','GOOG']
df = web.DataReader(ticks, 'yahoo', start, end)
names = list(df.columns.names)

df1 = df["Close"].shift() 
cols = [("New", col) for col in df1.columns]
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols,
                                        names=names)

df = df.join(df1)
```

Comment: thanks! You solved my problem but apparently your update looks like a better solution for my needs. I will try with some more complex shifting and filling, but it seems about right.

Comment: I see a trick is that you didn't create a new column first. I wanted to create a new one and then fill it with my calculation (like 1st row = 100, second row = first *xx, third=second*xx and so on.) doable by copying one and filling it but not elegant i supppose

Comment: df3 = df3.shift().fillna(100) * df['Close'] / df['Close'].shift().fillna(df['Close']) that seems the thing i want to do. first value = 100, second value depend on the first AND a calculation